# Can´t delete nested entities in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, cascading-deletes

I´ve got 3 entities Report, GaragingReport and GaragingReportData.

Report has a compsite key (reportid, userid). GaragingReport extends Report and has a List of GaragingReportData as a OneToMany relashionship.

I am trying to execute the following JPARepository query to delete all reports older than 90 days:

```
    void deleteByCreatedDateBefore(LocalDateTime expiryDate);
```

But I´m getting a constrain error telling me foreign keys cannot be null. I´ve allready set casecade.ALL and deleteOrphans = true but still no luck.

Report:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(Report.Keys.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@Table(name = "reports", schema = "public")
public class Report {

    @Id
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String id;

    @Id
    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name="userid")
    private String userid;

    @Getter @Setter
    private String name;

    @Getter
    @Column(name="created_date")
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
```

GaragingReport:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "garagingreports", schema = "public")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
public class GaragingReport extends Report {

    @OneToMany(
            cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @JoinColumns ({
            @JoinColumn(
                    name = "reportid",
                    referencedColumnName = "id"),
            @JoinColumn(
                    name = "userid",
                    referencedColumnName = "userid")
    })
    @Getter @Setter
    private List<GaragingReportData> data = new ArrayList<>();
```

GaragingReport Data:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(GaragingReportData.IdClass.class)
@Table(name = "garagingreportdata", schema = "public")
public class GaragingReportData implements CSVSerializable {

    private static final int CLUSTER_NUMBERS = 3;

    @Id
    @Getter @Setter
    private String reportid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(
                    name = "reportid",
                    referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(
                    name = "userid",
                    referencedColumnName = "userid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    @Getter @Setter
    private GaragingReport report;

    @Id
    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name = "userid")
    private String userid;

    @Id
    @Getter @Setter
    private String domain;

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name="garaging_metric")
    private Double garagingMetric;

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name="garaging_distance")
    private Double garagingDistance;

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name="strix_location_lat")
    private Double strixLocationLat;

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name="strix_location_lng")
    private Double strixLocationLng;

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name="strix_address")
    private String strixAddress;

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name="estimated_kms")
    private Double estimatedKms;


    @OneToMany(
            cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @JoinColumns ({
            @JoinColumn(
                    name = "reportid",
                    referencedColumnName = "reportid"),
            @JoinColumn(
                    name = "userid",
                    referencedColumnName = "userid"),
            @JoinColumn(
                    name = "domain",
                    referencedColumnName = "domain")
    })
    @Getter @Setter
    private List<GaragingReportDataCluster> clusters = new ArrayList<>();
```

Besides, if I try to delete a single entity I get the following exeption:
DataIntegrityViolationException - duplicate key. But I'm not inserting anything just repository.delete(report)

Thanks

Comment: try to delete the curly braces around {CascadeType.ALL} and see where that gets you.

Comment: Could you remove `updatable = false` from all `@JoinColumn`s and tell me if it helps?

Comment: Hi. I already tried with and without the braces. I suspect one problem is when trying to delete GaragingReport that is a subclass of Report. As I used JOIN strategy 2 tables are generated.

Comment: Hi @Andronicus. Removing updatable result in Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.strixtools.model.report.GaragingReportDataCluster column: domain (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Comment: I don't get what you just said...

Comment: If I remove updatable=false statement spring fails to Initialize because that reference is part of the primary key. So it detects as duplicate as reportid and userid are already present in the class as @Id